# Unable to add method to draw.io UML Interface 2 diagram

Tags: uml, draw.io

I am having some issues adding methods to UML class diagram. When I click on the bottom box, the cursor is there, and I can tab in it no issue:

[image: cursor in text box]

However, once I start typing, the line immediately shifts downwards:

[image: line shifts upwards]

I cannot find any method in resolving this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest to use an UML modeling tool rather than a drawing tool.

Comment: draw.io is a pretty standard UML modeling tool

Comment: Not at all. I use draw.io for e.g. cabling sketches and a few more things. So it's nice. But it's in no way an UML modelling tool. Just not as Visio (or Powerpoint).

Comment: I don't have this problem. Which browser do you use? If you create a new interface, you will have two default methods, method1 and method2. Can you modify these methods?

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Since we're talking UML: it's operation. A method is behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sample interface (Interface 2) from the toolbar on the left side of the window, in the UML section.

[image]

Then simply type your own methods instead of these.

[image]